# Android no Action Bar Shadown API Level 21

Tags: android, android-actionbar, shadow

Recently I noticed that the shadow of my action bar had disappeared, and when looking into it it appears that on KitKat devices the shadow is present but on Lollipop+ it remains non-existant. I feel it is as though something that I am missing from the docs and if someone could point me in the right direction it would be very helpful. Thank you in advance!

This is my styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="GenericTheme"
        parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/GenericActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/GenericActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="GenericActionBar"
        parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="background">@android:color/holo_blue_bright</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/holo_blue_bright</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Edit : No I am not using a tool bar

Comment: Are you using a `Toolbar`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want shadow in your Toolbar in API 21+ you have to add one XML attribute in the toolbar like this :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/tab_primary_color"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">  
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```